# the method[] cant be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be null. i am trying to read data form a collection in firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, provider

this is part of my product provider that i am calling on the homepage to return images and text to the screen. inside the product funtion at the element.data() i have tried to replace it with element.get('field value')the error disappears but nothing is written to the screen. im certain the issue is with null safety but adding ? or ! toelement.data?() or element.data!()  solves nothing. i dont know whta else to do kindly offer any insight

```
 List<Product> homeFeature = [];
  late Product homeFeaturedata;
  Future<void> gethomefeaturedata() async {
    List<Product> newlist = [];
    QuerySnapshot homeFeaturesnapshot =
        await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("homefeature").get();   
    homeFeaturesnapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
      var homeFeaturedata = Product(
          image: element.data()["image"],
          name: element.data()["name"],
          price: element.data()["image"]);
      newlist.add(homeFeaturedata);
    });

    homeFeature = newlist;
  }

  List<Product> get gethomefeaturelist {
    return homeFeature;
    
  }


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVveO.png
```

This is part of the homepage where i will be calling the data from the querysnapshot

```
 Row(
        children: homeFeaturedProduct.map((e) {
          return Expanded(
            child: Row(children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailView(
                              image: e.image, price: e.price, name: e.name)),
                    );
                  },
                  child: SingleProduct(
                      image: e.image, price: e.price, name: e.name),
                ),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                  onTap: (() {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => DetailView(
                              image: e.image, price: e.price, name: e.name)),
                    );
                  }),
                  child: SingleProduct(
                    image: e.image,
                    price: e.price,
                    name: e.name,
                  )),
                  
            ]),
          );
        }).toList(),
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

The bang operator (the exclamation mark) should come after the method call. So your case, `data!()` should actually be `data()!`.

Aside from that, I would suggest that if you use the same method more than once in an enclosure, it's better to take it out into a variable. Like so:

```dart
final feature = element.data()!;
newList.add(Product(
  image: feature["image"],
  name: feature["name"],
  price: feature["image"],
));
```

As a side note, you should pay attention to your naming convention. Dart recommends using `camelCase` for variables (and your IDE should have alerted you to this as well). For example, `homeFeaturedata` should be `homeFeatureData`, and `gethomefeaturedata` should be `getHomeFeatureData`.

Lastly, I don't think you need the `late Product homeFeaturedata;` statement, as it is not used outside of the `foreach` scope. Just replace the `var` with `final`.

Comment: i actually found another way but now its giving the bad state error and not returning anything to the screen this error has bugged me for days im stuck